# Div vertical align without defined height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering

Hi all been searching hard but found various answers that doesn't seem to resolve my issue.

I have one div box that needs to be vertically align centered to the div box next to it matching its height which is not defined as the content will change

But i need the content in the left box to be centered no matter what the height of the div box next to it.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="leftCol"> 
        Content or image in here needs to be vertical center based on div next to it height <
   /div>
   <div class="rightCol"> 
         Content here 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Show us what you have so far so we could help

Comment: <div class="container">
<div class="leftCol">
Content or image in here needs to be vertical center based on div next to it height
</div>
<div class="rightCol">
Content here
</div>
</div>

Comment: Sao. do not put in comments edit your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using CSS tables.

```css
.table-panel {
  display: table;
}
.table-panel div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-panel">
  <div>Left panel</div>
  <div>Right panel: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eu pulvinar risus. Vestibulum imperdiet velit nisi, eget ullamcorper urna rutrum vel. Aliquam tristique elit augue, nec lobortis eros pretium quis. Proin ac quam pretium,
    fringilla est et, sodales erat. Cras quis odio est. Integer ornare, neque in efficitur ultricies, justo magna ornare enim, quis dictum enim ipsum vel urna. Cras consectetur orci id quam cursus feugiat. Proin laoreet ullamcorper est vitae sagittis.
    Aliquam faucibus elit sed sodales varius. Phasellus maximus turpis non nisl lobortis, sit amet efficitur lacus suscipit. Nunc a ligula a est feugiat mollis in a lacus.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't complain about the use of tables here because I can't figure out how to do it another way :( +1 :P

Comment: @SaoTith Glad to help, remember to up vote the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right what you are looking for is a wrapper around the two left- and right-boxes. Then inside the wrapper you want the two boxes to be inline-blocks and with vertical-align:middle perhaps?

See this Fiddle:

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="left-box"></div>
  <div class="right-box"></div>
</div>

#wrap{
    width:250px;
    height:auto;
    background:#efefef;
}
.left-box{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
    background:#00ff00;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.right-box{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:180px;
    background:#ff0000;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0kpdskf2/

Is this what you want?

Comment: this would work if i defined a height but i can't defined a height as the content is depend on the data

Comment: It should work without defining the height for the right box? I just set the height for the example.